# Property "RightToLeftLayout"

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Hi every one I make a simple application that use the RightToLeftLayout Property in some forms  but the problem is when i open a form with "ShowDialog()" method and after this i activate this code

```
this.RightToLeftLayout = true;
this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

the form will closed automatically..
but when i use "Show()" method it will affected normally.

Please Can any one help me in this issue, I need to use "ShowDialog()" method in many forms in my project.

Comment: I think you should set the properties *before* you call `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: when i make this solution nothing happened. form layout has remained the same in the default look.